# Is there a prime number ending with the natural number $n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

if $n$ not is divisible by 2 or 5?

Example: given

```
  813075843967837637675737563754361301, there is a prime
20813075843967837637675737563754361301
```

or given

```
   31415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751, there is a prime
10331415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751
```

Etc.

Comment: If $n$ doesn't end with $2$ or $5$?? Well, what if $n$ ends with $4$, $6$, $8$, or $0$?

Comment: If the last digit of $n$ is one of $1,3,7,9$, then yes, there is a prime "ending with $n$". That follows from Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions.

Comment: [For any positive integer $n$, there are infinitely many primes *"beginning"* with $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_sequence#Examples), and [if $n$ "ends" with $1,3,5$, or $7$ then there are infinitely many primes *"ending"* with $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).

Comment: @r.e.s.: Yes, it follows from the very existence, since there comes a new ending from adding 1 to the most significant digit.

Comment: What do you mean? *What* follows from *what* very existence? (Note that there are *two* links in my previous comment.)

Comment: @r.e.s.: if there exist one prime ending with n, then you can add 1 to the most significant digit of that prime and - Voilà! - there must exist a new prime ending with that new number that is ending with n. Ad infinitum.

Comment: @r.e.s.: I certainly did miss that you meant the *beginning*! Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that $n$ should not end with $0,2,4,5,6$ or $8$ for anything to work. The rest will follow from [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)